# Laravel web installer error .env file

Tags: php, laravel

I install from git RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller and in the last stept i get an error when i try to install the .env file.

> FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>   Using $this when not in object context

```
private static function generateKey($outputLog)
{
    try{
        if (config('installer.final.key')){
            Artisan::call('key:generate', ["--force"=> true], $outputLog);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        return $this->response($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $outputLog;
}
```

Comment: Try updating the library. It looks like he's updated the code to use `static::response` instead of `$this->response` (updated 3 days ago)

Comment: how i do that ?

Comment: i install a few days ago mayby a week

Comment: Try `composer update` or `composer install`. If your composer.json is set up correctly, it will download and install the most recent updates

Answer (score 0):

This library has a clear bug in it with calling `$this` from a static context. Try installing Laravel using any of the multiple official ways: https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation

Comment: they just update the library one hour ago it works now thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed on: https://github.com/RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller/releases/tag/4.0.2

Pull the new version and it should work just fine.